# C#:Convert.ToBase64String problem

Tags: c#, base64

I'm new to C# development, 
the following code is Convert.ToBase64String  problem,
i don't know how to solve it.

```
 byte[] str1Byte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("xyz123");
 String plaintext = Convert.ToBase64String(str1Byte);

 byte[] plaintext_bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plaintext);
 Console.WriteLine("base64 plaintext: " + plaintext);
 Console.WriteLine("plaintext_bytes to String: " + 
                   System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plaintext_bytes));
 Console.WriteLine("ToBase64String(plaintext_bytes) : " + 
                   Convert.ToBase64String(plaintext_bytes));
```

Result:

```
base64 plaintext: eHl6MTIz 
plaintext_bytes to String: eHl6MTIz 
ToBase64String(plaintext_bytes) : ZUhsNk1USXo=
```

I expect the output of "`Convert.ToBase64String(plaintext_bytes))`" to be "`eHl6MTIz`", not "`ZUhsNk1USXo=`".

Comment: Why do you think, it should return this? `plaintext_bytes` contains `eHl6MTIz`. You are passing this value to `ToBase64String`. This means, you are base64 encoding plaintext_bytes... This surely will not result in the same value.

Comment: I'm curious, why convert a string to a byte array then to a base64 string. Is it to impair readability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to Base64 encode something that is already Base64 encoded:

```
// plaintext_bytes = eHl6MTIz 
Console.WriteLine("ToBase64String(plaintext_bytes) : " + Convert.ToBase64String(plaintext_bytes));
```

As mentioned, you need to go *FROM* base 64

Answer (score 1):

it shouldnt please have look to this article [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)

Base64 isn't Ascii representation of a string

Answer (score 0):

You make a confusion here: the Console.WriteLine you use will print some bytes, NOT the Base64 representation of the bytes. Base64 is a conversion algorithm, see link above.
And yes, use the FromBase64String

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it simply the case of you are encoding it twice?

byte[] str1Byte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("xyz123");

then

byte[] plaintext_bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plaintext);

(I was a bit slow, and Chris S states it more simply)